# Java Play 2.2 doesn't support javaagent

Tags: playframework, newrelic, playframework-2.2

With previous version of the Java Play framework, we could provide a command line argent to load monitoring agents.  For example, NewRelic could be loaded as

```
./path/to/start -javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar
```

With the release of the 2.2, the Play team has significantly changed the start script.  From what I can tell, it no longer supports javaagents.  Has any else gotten NewRelic running with Java Play 2.2+?  Play is great, but its useless tech if you can't monitor it in a production environment...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you can prefix *Java options* with `-J` (in a manner similar to *system properties* using `-D`):

```
$ bin/<app> -J-javaagent:lib/newrelic.jar
```

Discovered this while poking around in the script itself but it is noted in the usage summary:

```
$ bin/<app> -h
Usage:  [options]    
...
  -J-X               pass option -X directly to the java runtime
                     (-J is stripped)
...
```

Comment: Great find!!  The -J argument caused the NewRelic agent to get loaded.  For some reason the NewRelic logs indicate it's sending data, but NewRelic's web UI isn't updating.  I'll report back once I hear from their support team.

Comment: I seem to be getting data now.  Ironically, I think the collection was failing.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm still not getting data and the NewRelic support team says Play 2.2 isn't supported yet.  What version of the NewRelic library are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.21.4 (I just noted the latest version from https://newrelic.com/docs/releases/java).  It does appear to be working; but the app I'm testing with is trivial.  It did pick up an exception (thrown on purpose).  This is the first time I've used New Relic though (via Heroku); I suspect it will be best to wait until Play 2.2 is officially supported.

Comment: hi penfold - I'm not using heroku.  Heroku has pretty good support for Java Play and NewRelic.  I wonder if they're doing something special...

Comment: So It looks like I can get the agent started, but it doesn't report any data.  My command is './api-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/api -J-javaagent:/var/app/api/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.bootstrap_classpath=true'.  It looks like the -Dnewrelic.bootstrap_classpath=true isn't being honored, so no data is sent.  If others have this working, I'd love to see the command you're using to start Play...

Comment: I have the same problem, when I set the loglevel to "finer" I can see a transaction start and a transaction dispatch when using play 2.1. When using play 2.2 there is only a transaction start in the logfile, no dispatch

Comment: I have it working! Now I also have transactions. I needed to upgrade to the latest 3.0.1 agent.

Comment: Thanks Kris!!  I did NOT click the download link for NewRelic's Java Play agent.  Instead I downloaded their Java 3.0.1 package, installed it, used the same command above, and its working.  Thanks for pointing me toward the regular 3.0.1 Java package.

Answer (score 1):

With the new native packager in Play Framework 2.2 you need to set Java options in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: Hi James - Great suggestion.  When I attempted this, it worked for system properties with the -D flag, but didn't work for -J java options.  When I set the JAVA_OPTS export as "-J-javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.bootstrap_classpath=true", the javaagent wasn't started.

Comment: Bummer.  I'll investigate why this doesn't work.  it seems like it should.

Comment: I just set my JAVA_OPTS="-J-javaagent:path/java.newrelic-agent-3.0.1.jar" and it worked. (using play2.2, new relic, heroku)

Answer (score 0):

In Play Framework version 2.2, the application launch script changed to a different directory. To load the javaagent library, it is necessary to specify its full path.

For example, if **heroku-javaagent-1.4.jar** is in the project's **lib** directory:

```
heroku config:set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -javaagent:/app/lib/heroku-javaagent-1.4.jar=stdout=true,lxmem=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for PlayFramework 2.3.x
I copied the agent jar + yml config file to PLAY_APP_ROOT/lib

```
sbt start -J-javaagent:lib/newrelic.jar
```